# What is the error in the code below and how should it be corrected?

Tags: c++

What is the error in the code below and how should it be corrected?

```
my_struct_t *bar;
/* ... do stuff, including setting bar to point to a defined my_struct_t object ... */
memset(bar, 0, sizeof(bar));
```

Answer (score 2):

The last argument to `memset` is not right.

`sizeof(bar)` is the size of a pointer.

You need the size of an object. Use `sizeof(*bar)`.

```
memset(bar, 0, sizeof(*bar));
```